# Detaching editor in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to detach an editor from the main eclipse window?  I know this is possible with netbeans but so far I haven't been able to figure out how to do it (if possible) with eclipse.

Answer (score 26):

Selecting:  Window | New Window

Seems to be a close stand in for detaching the editor.  This command create a new "main eclipse window" so files can be opened and what not.

Comment: Nice trick! I just wanted to the detach the document but this works I guess :)

Answer (score 4):

With Eclipse Juno you can drag an editor out of the main window to detach it.