# Detached windows in Eclipse, is this possible?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way (plugin) in Eclipse to open detached windows which can be put on separate monitors: e.g one monitor will have my source, second threads and variables? The feature is in IntelliJ.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659728/detaching-editor-in-eclipse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  From the "Window" menu select "New Window".  You can also drag the tabs off of the main window and a new window with just that tab will be created.

If you want a window with just the source code by itself, dragging the tab with the source in it won't work.  What you can do is create the new window, drag the source over and minimize any other existing tabs within the new window to essentially leave a "source code only" view.  You should be able to save this as a perspective and name it "Editor Only".  This is somewhat cumbersome to setup, but once you have the perspective saved it should be pretty easy to get in and out of.

This is available in Helios and possibly earlier versions.

Comment: thanks a lot - some friends tell me that only IntelliJ has it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the title of any "View" and choose "Detach", this way you won't need two mail windows.